# External mic with iPhone and Bluetooth output

Tags: iphone, bluetooth, microphone

I need some way to control iPhone 5 to allow me use a external microphone in the headphone 3,5mm socket and output my voice (in real time) to an external bluetooth speaker via the mobile Bluetooth system in the phone. In fact it’s like using a mobile phone as a PA system. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

I found this app on App store that might suits your needs.

> Megaphone transforms your iPhone into an instant Microphone, PA system
>   or Megaphone when you plug it into amplified speakers.

https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/megaphone-free/id304955183?mt=8

As you plug in external microphone your system should switch to that input, same for the Bluetooth speakers as output.

Comment: I need to use an external mic and not a mic app as the external mic must be placed away from the phone connected by an audio cable. So far, I have found that when I place the external mic in the 3.5mm headphone socket in the phone, the bluetooth becomes deactivated and fails to communicate with the external bluetooth speaker.

Comment: That is because you plug is Mic+Headset speakers. You need a plug with microphone only.

Comment: Where at can I get a mic only that plus into the phone's headphone 3.5mm socket? Is there anyway way I can modify the white headphones I got with my iphone 5?

Answer (score 1):

No you cannot modify the white headphones you got. I'm assuming that your external mic is connected to some sort of audio panel right? If that's the case then you'll have to use an audio panel out to microphone in cable.

Or if you want a direct connection to your iPhone you could try using something like this;

http://www.canford.co.uk/Images/ItemImages/large/38-783_01.jpg

AFAIK if you use something like the above image, the iPhone will detect that you're using the jack as microphone in and not mic+headset speakers So it will then reoptimize and choose your bluetooth speaker for sound out.

Answer (score 0):

[I think there is] only one way to use your iPhone and Bluetooth speakers, connect *your* iPhone to BT speakers, then call *your* iPhone with *another* phone and now this other phone becomes your wireless mic.

Answer (score 0):

There is an app called crowd mic that will allow you to use your phone as mic broadcast over PA system, wirelessly.

Comment: Can you please link to it, and perhaps explain how to use it?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. The mic on my ipad is dead, can't figure out why and how. I don't want to purchase that expensive adapter either, but I did have a bluetooth microphone laying around. I connect my ipad to the bluetooth mic, then in order to override the internal mic, I plug the white headphone into the jack. Somehow it works.